# $.replaceWith() but without loosing event handlers and stuff

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, replacewith

I don't want to use `live()` or `on()` with delegation :/

Is there any other way to replace the element's HTML code but preserve the element data?

Comment: Can you please create an example of how you're implementing this? jsbin or plnkr would be great.

Comment: @thelocat If possible , can describe "element data" ? `event` data , `attributes`, `jQuery.data()` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you replace an HTML element via JavaScript, you remove its DOM node, and thereby all information associated with it.

There are (at least) two ways to deal with this:

- before replacing, save the data you need into a temporary variable and inject it after replacing (will most likely not work for event handlers).
- use an outer element which carries the data and handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the whole element with $.replaceWith(), try to change its attributes only.
Example (an icon that changes its state):

```
$.attr({title: "new title", src: "newIcon.png"})
```